# Error in Mutate ! non-numeric argument to binary operator in ShinyApp

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, reactive

I'm running into an error when I run the following code to create a ShinyApp

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#create sample dataframe
player1 <- c("Mario","Luigi")
player2 <- c("Luigi", "Mario")
pcnt_wins <- c(75,25)
pcnt_loss <- c(25,75)
data <- data.frame(player1, player2, pcnt_wins, pcnt_loss)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("char1", "Character 1:",
              c("Mario" = "Mario",
                "Luigi" = "Luigi")),
  tableOutput("data_table"),
  textOutput("text"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

#intermediate steps to create output table 
  table_filtered <- reactive({
    data %>% filter(names == input$char1) })
  
  character <- reactive({ # first column
    c(table_filtered()$player1, 
      table_filtered()$player2) })
  
  pie_win_pcnt <- reactive({ #second column
    c(as.double(table_filtered()$pcnt_wins),
      as.double(table_filtered()$pcnt_loss)) })
  
  pie_final <- reactive({
    data.frame(character(), pie_win_pcnt())
  })
 
#create table output 
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    pie_final()
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({ class(pie_final()$pie_win_pcnt) })
  
#create plot output 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    pie_final() %>%
      mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(100*pie_win_pcnt))), 
             pos = 100*pie_win_pcnt/2 + lead(csum, 1),
             pos = if_else(is.na(pos), 100*pie_win_pcnt/2, pos)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = "", y = 100*pie_win_pcnt, fill = character)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
      coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
      geom_col(width = 1, color =1) + 
      theme_void() +
      geom_label_repel(
        aes(y = pos, label = paste0(round(100*pie_win_pcnt,0), "%")),
        size = 6, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

```
Warning: Error in mutate: Problem while computing `csum = rev(cumsum(rev(100 * pie_win_pcnt)))`.
Caused by error in `100 * pie_win_pcnt`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am a bit confused because my variable pie_win_pcnt is a numeric variable in the dataframe pie_final. I feel like it is a problem with my intermediate steps to create the pie_final data.

The same code works when I run it in RMarkdown (without the reactive tables) so maybe I am messing up the reactive parts of this code? I would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: The issue that there is no column named `pie_win_pcnt` in `pie_final` ,i.e. the names are `c("character..", "pie_win_pcnt..")`. To fix that use `data.frame(character = character(), pie_win_pcnt  = pie_win_pcnt())` to create your dataset.